# Django: Passing **kwargs

Tags: python, django, keyword-argument

I have a question regarding passing `**kwargs`. In `views.py` I am collecting data such as `order_id` etc. This data I am passing to the charge function from where I call the `ChargeManager`. For each `def` I am passing currently the kwargs. However, I hoped to find a way that I only have to write it once in `views.py`. And then I can just use `**kwargs` to collect the data and pass them. However whatever I am trying I am struggling to get it working. Do you have any ideas why?

Example how I wanted it to work:

1)

```
paid = instance.charge(order_id=session_order_id, total=total, token=token)
```

2) `models.py`:

```
TransactionProfile
    def charge(self, **kwargs):
        return Charge.objects.stripe_charge(self, order_id, total, token)
```

3) `models.py`:

```
ChargeManager
    def stripe_charge(self, **kwargs): 
        print(order_id)
```

Currently, I have to do it this way:

`views.py`

```
paid = instance.charge(order_id=session_order_id, total=total, token=token)
```

`models.py`

```
def charge(self, order_id, total, token):
    return Charge.objects.stripe_charge(self, order_id, total, token)
```

`models.py`:

```
TransactionProfile
    def charge(self, order_id, total, token):
        return Charge.objects.stripe_charge(self, order_id, total, token)
```

`models.py`:

```
ChargeManager
    def stripe_charge(self, transaction_profile, order_id, total, token):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function accepts kwargs you can call another method with the same kwargs:

```
def charge(self, **kwargs):
    return Charge.objects.stripe_charge(self, transaction_profile=self, **kwargs)
```

If your `stripe_charge` method only accepts `kwargs`, you can no longer use `print(order_id)`. You've got to fetch it from `kwargs`:

```
def stripe_charge(self, **kwargs): 
    print(kwargs['order_id'])
```

I'm not sure I'd encourage you to use `**kwargs` like this. When I see the method `def charge(self, order_id, total, token):` it's immediately clear how to call it. `def charge(self, **kwargs)` is less clear.

Comment: Thank a lot for the answer and the advice @Alasdair 
I understand now where the problem was and I actually thought this is "DRY" but I understand your point and I will keep it as it is.

Comment: Yes, `**kwargs` is less repetitive, you could argue either way.

Comment: I have just one more question. I tested it out of curiosity with **kwargs however I always get "stripe_charge() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given". Do you have an idea where this comes from?

Comment: You'd get an error like that if you have a method which only takes kwargs, e.g. `def f(self, **kwargs)` and you called it with an argument e.g. `obj.f(arg1, **kwargs)`.